# Excel: Get Column values joined by Comma matching a user count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet named "days" which has  a Column C having workingdays of a particular  month ( 1 to 31 ).  [image]

I have another worksheet sheet named "allowance"   where user enters the Days count. For example if count  24 ,Get first 24 values from Column C in days sheet and join them  by Comma . Like below :

[image]

I am  able to generate them manually by using TEXTJOIN  to join values

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,days!C2:days!C25)   -------Get First 24 Values from Column C and join by Comma ..

How can i get the list generated  when user changes the count in Column ..

If user puts count as 15 .. i want
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,days!C2:days!**C16**)

Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

Three things I'd like to mention:

- The concatenated string seems to spill over into a next month's workdays. That would mean that column `C:C` does not hold the workdays for just a single month, right?
- All working-days seem to be 5 days in a row with a weekend in-between. I'd like to assume that the given sequence of workdays equals monday-friday and is not some custom range of days;
- If you have workdays in column `C:C` it would mean you have some sort of start-date you want to work from? In that case, I'd skip the idea of having these days seperate and generate the answer directly, see below:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,DAY(WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(B2,,0))))
```

---

**Note**: Make sure the start-date is an actual working-day.

---

**Edit:** In case the above does not apply to you and you do just want to pick a certain amount of rows from a range, try either:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,CHOOSEROWS(<YourRange>,SEQUENCE(24)))
```

Or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,INDEX(<YourRange>,SEQUENCE(24)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JvdV for helping me out .    .  Yes , I have a Start date and End date where i calculate number of working days with no custom weekend  .. It does not spill over a month .. This worked for me .. =TEXTJOIN(",",,DAY(WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(B2,,0))))

Comment: @TarunGupta, glad it helped. Consider to close the thread and click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

THanks @jvDV .  I am closing this thread  as asked.

This worked for me .. =TEXTJOIN(",",,DAY(WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(B2,,0))))